# Getting infinity when should be getting percent

Tags: java, math

Here is the output I'm getting
"1 student(s) passed: Infinity"
when I should be getting 100% instead of Infinity. Any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class PassFailCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char grade;
        int numFails = 0;
        int numPass = 0;
        float percentFailed;
        float percentPassed;

        do {

            System.out.print("Enter a grade: ");
            grade = 'A';

            if (grade == 'A' || grade == 'B' || grade == 'C' || grade == 'D') {
                numPass++;
            } else {
                numFails++;
            }
            grade = 'Z';

        } while (grade != 'Z');

        percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / numFails;
        System.out.println(numPass + " student(s) passed: " + percentPassed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are dividing by 0.

Comment: what if no one failed `numFails = 0` divide by `Zero` is infinity. Percentage pass = (numPass*100)/totalAppeared.

Comment: Please see this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542536/why-is-number-divided-by-zero-infinity-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the percentage passed, you need to divide by the *total*, not the number failed.

```
float percentPassed = (((float) numPass) / (numPassed + numFailed)) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / (numPass+numFails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing a `float` by zero, which gives infinity.

That is the case when `numFails` is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       grade = 'Z';

    } while (grade != 'Z');
```

You are executing exactly one iteration through your loop. If `numFails` happens to remain zero after it, division by zero ensues.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wronfg formula for getting the percentage

Instead of ,

```
 percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / numFails;
```

it should be

```
 percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / totalNumOfStudents;
```

Also, the issue as rightly pointed is divide by zero which results to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide numPass by numTotal, not numFails. Smth like this:

```
public class PassFailCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char grade;
    int numTotal = 0;
    int numPass = 0;
    float percentFailed;
    float percentPassed;

    do {

        System.out.print("Enter a grade: ");
        grade = 'A';

        if (grade == 'A' || grade == 'B' || grade == 'C' || grade == 'D') {
            numPass++;
        }
        numTotal++;
        grade = 'Z';

    } while (grade != 'Z');

    if (numTotal != 0) {
        percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / numTotal;
    }
    System.out.println(numPass + " student(s) passed: " + percentPassed);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**The reason you are getting `Infinity`** is because you are dividing by 0 with floats (numFails == 0).  (If you hadn't cast your division to a float, you would have gotten:
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`!)

**What you need to do** is divide by the *total* number of scores, not just the number of failing scores.  Like so:

```
percentPassed = (float) numPass * 100 / (numPass + numFails);
```